# .catch(e => {console.error(e.error))} gives undefined error (setting up stripe)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

So, I am trying to set up stripe with a video form WebDevSimplified (since I am not experienced with coding) and tried combining it with my website. After trying to google the solution I couldn't find anything that helped or was similar to my situation. This is part of my main.js file:

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready() //line 4
}

function ready() {

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked) //line 26
```

```
function purchaseClicked() {
    fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            items: [
                { id: 1, quantity: 3},
                { id: 2, quantity: 1}
            ]
        })
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) return res.JSON()
            return res.JSON().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
        })
        .then(({url}) => {
            console.log(url)
            //window.location = url
        })
        .catch(e => { //line 62
            console.error(e.error) //line 63
        })
    }
}
```

And this is the error in my console:

```
purchaseClicked http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:63
    (Async: promise callback)
    purchaseClicked http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:62
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    ready http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:26
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:4
```

(The server is in node if it is relevant)
Help would be much appreciated!

I was Expecting to not get any errors with catch error but to get an error saying API is missing .

Comment: try `console.error(e)` instead of `console.error(e.error)` and you'll see what your error is - hint: the error will be regarding `res.JSON`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Changed JSON to json and the error is now fixed.